Conditions so that relative homotopy equivalent is the same
In the following question: homology relative to homotopy equivalent subspaces it is shown that if $A$ and $B$ are two subspaces of a topological space $X$ then it is not true that if
$A$ and $B$ are of the same homotopy type then the relative homology
$H_*(X,A;\mathbb Z)\cong H_*(X,B;\mathbb Z)$.
In a footnote there is written that this is true if "there exists a map which is an homotopy equivalence from $f:A \rightarrow U$ such that the inclusion $i_1: A \subset X$ is homotopic to the composition $i_2 \circ f$, where $i_2: B \subset X$."
Does someone has a reference for this?

I suspect this is still false in this generality. It would seem natural to add the assumption that both inclusions are cofibrations (or perhaps, as in Tyler Lawson's comment, good pairs).

So do you this it may work if $A$ is a closed set "tame enough" to have a tubular neihbourhood and with $B$ its tubular neighbourhood?

If $A$ is a subset of $B$ and the inclusion $A\subseteq B$ is a homotopy equivalence, the result holds by the LES of a triple. That's a much more specific case, though.
